# Server 2008 R2 Firewall configuration

Tags: windows-firewall

I have Win Server 2008 R2 with AD, DNS, DHCP and Fileserver roles installed. I have enabled windows firewall. Server is loceted in internal secure network. What extra security rules should I add to the firewall? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I don't add any.  The defaults are pretty sane.  It's restrictive by default and only opens up ports for the roles you add.

Comment: +1. Windows Firewall is based on a "whitelist" mentality, which means anything not specifically allowed is denied by default. If you come across a program that won't work, then you just need to open the firewall for that port.

Comment: There is only one exception I've found - on a multi-site network, the domain controllers seem to reject requests from other subnets, and only respond to sites in their own subnet. This is easy fixed though.